# App is not keeping its spot for more than 20 mins if movieplayer is pause and app close

Tags: iphone, mpmovieplayercontroller

I am using `MpMoviePlayerController` for playing Audio/Video files from server. If I play the audio from server and pause it and close the app and after 20 minutes the app gets started from beginning not from the last spot. Thanks for help in advance...

Answer (score 0):

It is because app will stop working in background after 10 minutes. 
But, you can make it keep running in background for long time. 
Check these links:- 
[Run app for more than 10 minutes in background](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9738488/run-app-for-more-than-10-minutes-in-background),
 [iOS: Keep application running in background](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10674004/ios-keep-application-running-in-background) and 
 http://blog.dkaminsky.info/2013/01/27/keep-your-ios-app-running-in-background-forever/

Comment: Ya but if i am not using movieplayer then it won't terminate either.

Comment: Check this:- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9738488/run-app-for-more-than-10-minutes-in-background

Comment: Hi Piyush,its not the proper solution. The app gets rejected by apple by using this approach. So is there any other solution???