# LUA Making my app real-time iOS

Tags: lua

I have no idea on how to create my app to become real-time,

what I wanted to do is it alerts the user of something, and when the app is closed it will alert you via notification.

I've done on how to alert the user while the app is on, but i don't know if the app is off/closed.

Comment: You will need to provide more information about what you are doing and the environment of your Lua application.  There are lots of different kinds of notifications.  For instance are you wanting to send a message of some kind, display a dialog box, create a log, or what?

Comment: You probably aren't *actually* referring to [real-time](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Real-time_operating_system).

Answer (score 0):

What you are trying to do is a form of background processing. Look at [iOS: Keep application running in background](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10674004/ios-keep-application-running-in-background).