# App will not update itself when running in the background

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch

My app is not updating the information from the web services when the app is running in the background.

```
-(void)onTick:(NSTimer *)timer {
    [self parseData];
    [self.tableView reloadData];

}
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    NSDate *d = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow: 60.0];
    NSTimer *t = [[NSTimer alloc] initWithFireDate: d
                                          interval: 30.0
                                            target: self
                                          selector:@selector(onTick:)
                                          userInfo:nil repeats:YES];

NSRunLoop *runner = [NSRunLoop currentRunLoop];
[runner addTimer:t forMode: NSDefaultRunLoopMode];

}
```

If the app is visible than everything goes smooth, as soon as it gets put into the background it does not update the data until i bring the app to the foreground again.

Any ideas or suggestions to what is causing this?

Much appreciated.

Comment: possible duplicate of [iOS: Keep application running in background](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10674004/ios-keep-application-running-in-background)

Answer (score 0):

To save resources on iOS device, the Operating System doesn't not update/draw UIView that are not visible.

Also, unless your application request permissions, your app will be suspended in the background.

From Apple Docs [The View Drawing Cycle](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/uiview_class/uiview/uiview.html)

> View drawing occurs on an as-needed basis. When a view is first shown, or when all or part of it becomes visible due to layout changes, the system asks the view to draw its contents.