# Cordova: Run events when app in background

Tags: cordova, phonegap-plugins

Is it possible to run events, if the app is in the background of my iPad?
(The app is not closed, but in the background.)

I have an event that runs if my device gets an internet connection.
When the app runs normally it works.

If i set up the internet connection and the app is in the background --> nothing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apps moving to the background are expected to put themselves into a quiescent state as quickly as possible so that they can be suspended by the system. If your app is in the middle of a task and needs a little extra time to complete that task, it can call the `beginBackgroundTaskWithName:expirationHandler:`

Please see documetation [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/BackgroundExecution/BackgroundExecution.html)

but if you want to run in background you have to jailbreak your iphone,[iOS: Keep application running in background](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10674004/ios-keep-application-running-in-background)

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible, only on Android it is possible to run the app in the background. On iOS you do not have this possibility.