# Read up notification from locked screen

Tags: ios, swift, notifications, text-to-speech

I have my application which has notifications that the user can receive. I once used an application that read the notifications from the lock screen, so the scenario:

1. User received notification when the phone was locked
2. The notification was automatically read up by the system from the lock screen

Does anyone have experience from this and how to do this? Have googled and could not find anything.

Comment: I doubt that this can be done!

Comment: You probably can run application on background, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10674004/ios-keep-application-running-in-background and check notifications periodically