# Fetch data in iOS with flutter even if the application is terminated

Tags: ios, flutter, mobile

I'm developing an application using flutter, and I need to run some code in the background to fetch some user data from a server (REST API) 2 times a day.

I checked many libraries everything is working fine in Android even if the application is terminated, but unfortnantly it's not working on iOS when the application is terminated, is there any way or any techniques that I should implement to do this?

Comment: You can schedule local notifications/alarms that will wake up the app (in bg) and then you can pull data.

Comment: Please refer the link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10674004/ios-keep-application-running-in-background it will help you to achieve your requirement